# Trouble Printing a Matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, printing

I think it comes down to the **data type** im using for the contents of the matrix, but after searching for a while I can't seem to find a definitive answer as to how it **should** look. On the other hand if you see something wrong with a different part let me know too. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
  double a[][3] = {
                    {1.,2./3.,3.},
                    {4.,5.,6.},
                    {7.,8.,9.}
                   };
  int x, y;

  for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    printf("\n\t\t");
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
      printf("%5d", a[x][y]);
    }//End y loop
  }//End x loop

  printf("\n\n\t");
  system("pause");

  return 0;
} //End main
```

The code output looks like this:

```
          01610612736    0
          0    0    0
          0    0    0
```

Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%d stands for integer, you want %f for double in printf(). It's kind of misleading but %d **doesn't** stand for double.

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it. Cant mark it as solved another few minutes, but I tested it already. Thanks for the fast response! I guess I just needed a fresh pair of eyes =)

Comment: Great. It's hard to find error if you are completely convinced it isn't there :D

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%5d", a[x][y]);`
The `%d` in this line is telling printf to interpret the bits you pass as an int.  However, you are passing it a floating-point value, which is why you are getting strange output.  To print a double, you need to use `%f`.
See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf for more on what data types and sizes different printf specifiers expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link! I will definitely be referencing it in the future.